# How to style a psuedo element with a pseudo class using Styletron

Tags: javascript, css, jss, styletron

In attempting to add a material design ripple animation to a button I took a pure css implementation [here](https://github.com/mladenplavsic/css-ripple-effect/blob/master/dist/ripple.css) and used it.

But now we're migrating to [Styletron](http://styletron.js.org/). How do I recreate this

```
.ripple-class {
  /* props */
}

.ripple-class:after {
  /* props */
}

.ripple-class:active:after {
  /* props */
}
```

in styletron? I've tried this

```
injectStyles(styletron, {
  // ripple-class props
  ':after': {
    // :after props
  },
  ':active:after': {
    // more props
  }
});
```

And

```
injectStyles(styletron, {
  // ripple-class props
  ':after': {
     // :after props
  },
  ':active': {
    ':after': {
       // more props
    }
  }
});
```

The button does not animate. If I just put the actual css in a style tag it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one you tried should work, but you have to double-wrap the `content` property in quotes otherwise it won't have a value in the resulting CSS (and the whole `:after` pseudo is then ignored by CSS for having a wrong value for the `content` property):

```
injectStyles(styletron, {
    // ripple-class props
    ':after': {
        content: '""',                  // '""' (literally "") is the value not '' (literally nothing)
        // :after props
    },
    ':active:after': {
        content: '""',
        // more props
    }
});
```

Because `':after': { content: '' }` will result in CSS that look like this `:after { content: }` which is wrong.

Whereas `':after': { content: '""' }` will result in CSS that look like this `:after { content: ""}` which is correct.